# Reinstalling 13.10

Tags: installation, 13.10

So I was super hyped when i saw 13.10 came out. I immediately updated, and upon restart something didn't seem quite right. Most of the system default icons, (trash, settings, etc..) have no image. The bar at the top with the time and date and other settings like logging out, also are missing. I am missing all sound. I cannot open software and updates under system settings, and I get an error when attempting to do so. Is there anyway I can attempt to re install 13.10 to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 13.10 has plenty of bugs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following in a terminal to attempt to fix the issue:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade -y; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y; sudo apt-get install -f -y; sudo aptitude upgrade -y; sudo aptitude dist-upgrade -y; sudo aptitude install ubuntu-desktop unity-tweak-tool -y
```

Use Unity Tweak Tool to change icons/themes if Ubuntu is not using the correct ones.

Comment: I thought it was fixed, but apparently audio is still a no go.

Comment: For the audio, try 'sudo rm ~/.pulse* ~/.config/pulse* ~/.asoundrc -R' then log out and log back in. Also try running alsamixer, selecting your sound card with F6, and making sure nothing is muted (M to toggle).

Comment: I don't have anything called pulse, or asoundrc. Everything seems to be selected properly in alsamixer, and nothing appears to be muted.

Comment: Sorry that I can't help you further with the audio. Honestly, I can't get my Creative Recon3D to work in Ubuntu 13.10 even after I installed it 4 times, but it works in Ubuntu 13.04 so I stuck with that. My other machines with onboard audio though work fine. You might want to issue the audio thing as a seperate issue/bug to get more attention to it.